# Не получается компилировать программу в apk с помощью buildozer

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, buildozer

Делал всё как по этому гайду, но на финальном этапе возникает ошибка.
Bот ссылка на ошибку, потому что не могу ее сюда вставит: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/pCi45zTS3_5WTQ